# What makes a Min(byte,int) call ambiguous?

Tags: c#, byte, ambiguous-call

I do not understand why the following is ambiguous according to compiler:

```
byte x = 200; 
int novaCervena = Math.Min(x, 10);
```

And once I add +1 to byte it is not

```
byte x = 200; 
int novaCervena = Math.Min(x+1, 10);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's definitely not ambiguous when you use `x+1` as the type of the first argument is then `int`. (There's no `byte+byte` operator in C#.)

In the first case, you have a `byte` argument which can be implicitly converted to an `int`, but then an integer literal argument. The argument is of type `int`, but with an implicit constant expression conversion to `byte` (see section 6.1.9). So while both `Min(byte, byte)` and `Min(int, int)` are applicable overloads, each is "preferred" for a different parameter (due to the conversions available), hence the ambiguity.

Note that if you have a "normal" expression of type `int` (as opposed to a constant expression) the ambiguity goes away:

```
byte x = 200;
int y = 10;
int z = Math.Min(x, y); // Uses Math.Min(int, int)
```

Likewise a normal `byte` argument:

```
byte x = 200;
byte y = 10;
byte z = Math.Min(x, y); // Uses Math.Min(byte, byte)
```

Or you can force the conversion either way:

```
byte x = 200;
byte z = Math.Min(x, (byte)10); // Uses Math.Min(byte, byte)

byte a = 200;
int b = Math.Min((int) a, 10); // Uses Math.Min(int, int)
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. So I need to cast to int

Comment: @lojol: If you want it to use the `int` version, yes.

Comment: @lojol: You _can_ have an expression `byte + byte`, there's just no operator explicitly defined for it.  The compiler will promote both operands to `int` in that case so it can use the `int + int` operator.  So you can write such an expression, there's just no operator to do it directly.  It's important for you to understand the distinction.

Answer (score 4):

I assume in the first case it can't choose between `Min(byte,byte)` and `Min(int,int)`.

Operations on `byte` *always* result in an `int`, so `x+1` is `int` and there is no ambiguity - it has to choose `Min(int,int)`.